# Should I reinstall ubuntu

Tags: permissions

I am a new to ubuntu. Windows 10 so screwed up that I am done with MS. My computer has two hard drives, a 240 gig SSD for programs and boot, and a 2TB for data, video, and the rest. When my install got started I could see the SSD but could not access the drive. The error statement said windows was not closed correctly and therefore could not access the drive. So in an attempt to fix that problem I deleted the windows section of the SSD. Now I cannot see the drive by itself. When I go to the comand line I can create files and  delete files but I cannot change directories.

```
larry@10628:~$ ls -l
total 472
-rw-rw-r-- 1 larry larry      0 Nov  2 23:12 adminsitration
drwxr-xr-x 2 larry larry   4096 Oct 15 09:14 Desktop
drwxr-xr-x 2 larry larry   4096 Oct 15 09:14 Documents
drwxr-xr-x 3 larry larry   4096 Oct 31 12:14 Downloads
-rw-r--r-- 1 larry larry   8980 Oct 15 09:07 examples.desktop
drwxr-xr-x 2 larry larry   4096 Oct 15 09:14 Music
-rw-rw-r-- 1 larry larry 408970 Nov  3 08:09 opencpn.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 larry larry      0 Nov  2 23:12 OS-Uninstaller
drwxr-xr-x 2 larry larry   4096 Oct 15 09:14 Pictures
drwxr-xr-x 2 larry larry   4096 Oct 15 09:14 Public
drwxr-xr-x 2 larry larry   4096 Oct 15 09:14 Templates
-rw-rw-r-- 1 larry larry     62 Oct 30 16:26 test1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 larry larry     35 Oct 30 16:21 test1~
-rw-rw-r-- 1 larry larry  18459 Oct 22 23:21 Unnamed
drwxr-xr-x 2 larry larry   4096 Oct 15 09:14 Videos
larry@10628:~$ cd/downloads
bash: cd/downloads: No such file or directory
larry@10628:~$
```

Does this have something to do with mounting ?
I am taking a course online about ubuntu but I still do not have a clue.

Thanks in advance for your kind assistance.

Answer (score 2):

`cd/downloads` is wrong. It is `cd ~/Downloads` to go (from anywhere) to the Downloads directory inside your "home". Mind the space after `cd`, mind the `~` in front of the `/` and mind the capital d.

`cd` is the command and needs a space at the end of it (otherwise it would assume it is another command).

The "~" is used to indicate the current users home directory (ie. `/home/$USER).

Linux is case-sensitive so "downloads" and "Downloads" are 2 different things. Your `ls` shows

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 larry larry   4096 Oct 31 12:14 Downloads
```

and not

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 larry larry   4096 Oct 31 12:14 downloads
```